# Concatenate text files in a specific order with Bash

Tags: bash

Say I have a directory containing 5 files :

```
file1.md
another file.md
and yet another one.md
some other file.md
And the last one.md
```

Files may have spaces in their name.

Now suppose I have a file containing an ordered list of the filenames above :

```
And the last one.md
another file.md
and yet another one.md
file1.md
some other file.md
```

What Bash script could I use in order to concatenate all six files into a new one, following the order defined in the ordered list ? I'm using Bash on Windows.
The context is that I want to be able to reorder small parts of a larger text, such as short stories or chapters in a book.

Comment: You could read the second file into an array, and then do something like `cat "${arr[@]}"`. Did you bump into a specific problem?

Answer (score 3):

The following should be just enough:

```
xargs -d '\n' cat < file_containing_an_ordered_list_of_the_filenames.txt
```

Comment: May need pre-processing if `file_containing_an_ordered_list_of_the_filenames.txt` uses `\r\n` record separators

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`while read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208911/while-read-loop).

```
rm output.txt;cat input.txt | while read row; do cat "$row" >> output.txt; done
```

Alternatively:

```
while read row; do cat "$row"; done < input.txt > output.txt
```

The command reads rows from the `input.txt` and appends the contents of the files to the `output.txt`. [Double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151807/how-to-pass-argument-with-spaces-to-a-shell-script-function) are good for spaces in file names.

My attempt:

Creating data (optional):

```
 while read row; do echo "$row" "mm" > "$row"; done
```

> Shift + Ins
> Ctrl + c

```
$ cat file1.md
file1.md mm
$ ls -1
'And the last one.md'
'and yet another one.md'
'another file.md'
file1.md
input.txt
output.txt
'some other file.md'
```

Output:

```
$ cat output.txt
And the last one.md mm
another file.md mm
and yet another one.md mm
file1.md mm
some other file.md mm
```

Change order of names:

```
$ cat input.txt
another file.md
and yet another one.md
some other file.md
And the last one.md
file1.md

$ rm output.txt;cat input.txt | while read row; do cat "$row" >> output.txt; done

$ cat output.txt
another file.md mm
and yet another one.md mm
some other file.md mm
And the last one.md mm
file1.md mm
```